# Query to see last 6 months records?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
select sum(Invoice_Amount) as Invoice_amount,
       COUNT(*) as Invoice_Count 
from Payment_Exception pe
  inner join Invoice_Details ind on ind.Customer_ReferenceId = pe.Id 
where pe.Customer_Code = '1001012'
  and ind.Status='Submit'
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you have a `datetime`column that you want to compare with last 6 months?

Comment: yes sir i have Insert_date column

Comment: This is a bad example of [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: If you have Insert_date then why you are not using it in your query? What is your problem actually?

Comment: yeah i used it now it's working ,i didn't no how to used it?

Comment: Which dbms? (Datetime functionality is too often not ANSI SQL compliant...)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, provide a concise and clear formulation of your problem. Throwing out code without any words is not productive and rude.

Comment: @HemantMane first you must explain your problem briefly in question . Then you can get solution properly

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(Invoice_Amount) as Invoice_amount,COUNT(*) as Invoice_Count 
from Payment_Exception pe inner join Invoice_Details ind on ind.Customer_ReferenceId=pe.Id 
where pe.Customer_Code='1001012' and ind.Status='Submit'  
and ind.invoice_date>=DATEADD(m,-6,getdate())
group by Invoice_Amount
```

You need to add group by condition also .

Comment: Which dbms is this for? (Product specific functions are used...)

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(Invoice_Amount)
as Invoice_amount,COUNT(*) as Invoice_Count
from Payment_Exception pe 
inner join Invoice_Details ind on ind.Customer_ReferenceId=pe.Id 
where pe.Customer_Code='1001012' and ind.Status='Submit' and  
ind.Insert_Date > dateadd(m, -6, getdate() - datepart(d, getdate()) + 1)
```

Comment: Which dbms is this for? (Product specific functions are used...)

Comment: Have you edit your question or you got solution from your side ??